# Pixiedust not displaying in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, pixiedust

I installed **Pixiedust** using **conda**. I am trying to use in Jupyter Lab. But When I run a comand it only diplays: Ipython.core.display.Javascript object. The following picture illustrates the error:

[image]

Comment: It is not an error. Try printing it. Also, avoid using in-built functions as variable names, in this case `max`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/07/pixie-debugger-python-debugging-tool-jupyter-notebooks-data-scientist-must-use/) it specifically states that:

> PixieDebugger, developed by the PixieDust team, claims to be the first
>   visual debugger for Python that works exclusively with Jupyter
>   Notebooks. **Note that it doesn’t yet work with JupyterLab** but the
>   developers might be working on fixing this soon.

as of JULY 25, 2018

Comment: Thanks! This seems to hold for 18 November 2020 as well.

Comment: Was looking forward to using with jlab. Sad times.

Comment: @Dee yep, I feel you. bummer! maybe 2021?

Comment: in 7 days, that'd be great haha
https://github.com/jupyterlab/debugger this looks pretty good as well, unfortunately I work in a ringfenced system and can't find out to update nodejs to the newest version to use it, you might be able to enjoy it tho!

Comment: @Dee if anything changes I'll update my answer. Best